# Insert double quotes around all html tag attribute

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

am trying to convert html  to xml , but  double quotes of html tag attribute doesn't work 

so when convert it to xml gives me error 
so how can i add double quotes to all to my xml file ,
am using vb.net windows form application

Comment: could you please provide a small example and tell what doesn't work

Comment: Also, html != xml. What are you trying to achieve, there may be a better solotion

Comment: sorry the html actually structured same like XML structure the problem only  with tags attributes values for example
<ol><a name="a1"> anchor content </a></ol> this is in html when i convert it to xml i got this
<ol><a name=a1>what</a></ol> without double quotes in attribute values in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

converting an `html` to `xml` would **not** work..There are various corner cases where your `html` to `xml` conversion may **fail**

The best way to convert html to xml would be to:

1>Extract relevant data from the `html` using parsers like [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

2>Store those extracted data into `xml` using various xml api's like [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) or [Linq2Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: sorry the html actually structured same like XML structure the problem only  with tags attributes values for example
<ol><a name="a1"> anchor content </a></ol> this is in html when i convert it to xml i got this
<ol><a name=a1>what</a></ol> without any double quotes which gives me error as xml file

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what method you use to convert. You say nothing abour that. Nevertheless, it's obviously this method which is the core problem. And maybe also what you plan to do once the html is converted into xml ?

To tell the truth, no conversion is needed given that html **is** already xml (well-formed html at least). Simply load your html in a `XDocument` for example... and that's it. Nothing special to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please :

- install SgmlReader from nuget
- in case you have a string variable like below you will have to convert it into a TextReader object.

Now we are going to use the package installed.

```
static XmlDocument HTMLTEST()
        {
            string html = "<table frame=all><tgroup></tgroup></table>";
            TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);

            Sgml.SgmlReader sgmlReader = new Sgml.SgmlReader();
            sgmlReader.DocType = "HTML";
            sgmlReader.WhitespaceHandling = System.Xml.WhitespaceHandling.All;
            sgmlReader.InputStream = reader;

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;  //false if you dont want whitespace
            doc.XmlResolver = null;

            doc.Load(sgmlReader);

            return doc;
        }
```

Input is string html format, and the return will be doc XmlDocument format.
Your frame=all from html will become frame="all".

Comment: Also, if you want to clear some of your html string code, just use Regex. For instance you may not want style attribute:  pattern= @"style='\b[^']*'"; html= Regex.Replace(html,pattern,string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);